# Eliminate duplicate results in a select query that contains CLOB column

Tags: oracle, distinct

This is the select query:

```
select orderid,ordernum,orderdate,orderxml from orders
```

The query returns multiple rows with same ordernum. I tried to use DISTINCT and Group BY but orderxml is a clob column.
How can I eliminate duplicate ordernums in my query?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate `ordernum` in your table? Do they have the same values for `orderdate` and `orderxml`? If not, which values do you need to select for those columns?

Comment: Yes, they have same values for orderdate and orderxml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an analytic function to identify a single `orderid` for each `ordernum` - probably either min or max, but other functions are available, it depends on what you need - in a subquery, and then filter to only get the rows with the identified IDs:

```
select orderid, ordernum, orderdate, orderxml
from (
  select orderid, ordernum, orderdate, orderxml,
    max(orderid) over (partition by ordernum) as maxorderid
  from orders
)
where orderid = maxorderid;
```

The inline view gets all the columns and rows from your table, but adds an additional column to its result that has the maximum ID across all rows with the same order number. (You can add any other filters you want in there, or course).

The outer filter then only matches the ID for each order number that matches that maximum value.

This assumes that `orderid` is unique - at least for an `ordernum` but presumably globally. You said the `orderdate` is always the same for the `ordernum` but you could include that in the partition by if not, possibly modifying the analytic function used.

(And then investigate how and why you are getting duplicates, and try to stop them; then remove the duplicates from your table - carefully...)